# as.Date does not error out when it should

Tags: r

Consider the code block below.

```
strDates<-c("01/01/2019","08/16/1975")
d<-as.Date(strDates,"%m/%d/%y")
d
[1] "2020-01-01" "2019-08-16"
```

Clearly, the answer is incorrect. The issue is that the %y should be %Y because it is %Y that accepts year with four characters. But shouldn't as.Date error out because of this failed match. Instead, it gives an incorrect answer. Is this poor design or is there any reason for the function not failing, and instead returning an incorrect reply?

Comment: It shouldn't error because `%y` is also valid and returns what it should(see the docs).**Year without century (00–99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 – that is the behaviour specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the..**

Comment: The only thing that might be unclear in the documentation is the characters beyond the format specification length are silently ignored.

Comment: @42- Yes. And I think this is a weakness. There is no justification for considering only the first two characters when %y is supposed to match exactly 2 characters.

Comment: Trailing characters are ignored to allow input where excessive numeric precision or superfluous time zone information is supplied. It is assumed that you know both the format of your input data and the correct format string.

Comment: @42 What "excessive numeric precision" can be there in the specification of year? I don't think assumptions can be made where there is scope for computation of an incorrect but valid output should the input not be of the expected format.

Comment: The striptime function also handles date-times. And I suggest you design and implement a function to apply the strict error trapping you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. As stated in `?strptime`:

> %y
>   Year without century (00–99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 – that is the behaviour specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the default century inferred from a 2-digit year will change’.

Essentially what happens for this question is that the year part is ignored and prefixed as defined in the docs.
So

```
c("01/01/2019","08/16/1975")
```

Since 2019(the 20 part) is in the range 00 to 68, the prefix is 20 and since 19(from 1975) is also in the same range, the resulting years are 2020 and 2019. As stated in the docs and by @42-, `strptime` only deals with the first two digits of the year part when using `%y%`

> future version the default century inferred from a **2-digit year** will change

Comment: So %y matches two characters. If four characters are there in the year, the call should fail immediately without further computation. What is the justification for ignoring the last two characters of the year? A simple if(len(year)>2) then fail for %y is desirable. It saves a lot of debugging effort, and, more importantly, that is the more rational choice for the behavior of the function. The standard describes the nuance but, in my view, that is no excuse for this apparently unnecessary complication unless there is another angle to this.

Comment: I am unfortunately not able to answer the justification. Someone on the RCore Team might be more ideal. I however think that it was assumed that `%y` would only be used on 2 digit years(hence the without century). I'm not sure if this varies in other languages.

Comment: Assumptions can led to issues such as these. Routines must be robust. I am inclined to conclude that this is just a case of weak design as I initially considered as a possibility.

Comment: The decision to ignore trailing characters allows dropping trailing time zone or excessive precision in datetime input. You can replace strptime with a routine that adds additional protection if you so desire. You might want to look at the “anytime” package.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments indicate junk after the data is ignored but note that you can provide a vector of formats using the `tryFormats` argument in which case it will use the appropriate one.

```
strDates <- c("01/01/2019","08/16/1975", "01/01/00")
as.Date(strDates, tryFormats = c("%m/%d/%y", "%m/%d/%Y"))
## [1] "2020-01-01" "1975-08-16" "2000-01-01"
```

Comment: I think this is being recycled since 00 becomes 2000(although coincidentally in this case it doesn't make a difference) and 2019 becomes 2020 via the recycling of the format vector.

Comment: I have added the argument name, `tryFormats`, to ensure it is using the correct one.

Comment: Another problem with the ignoring of characters with the %y is that "01/01/2019" fits "%m/%d/%y" since it occurs first in tryformats although "%m/%d/%Y" is the correct fit, and would produce the correct result.